# Is this "as superior as" construction grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, metaphors

Such an excellent king, as superior to my uncle as a god is to a beast,

Comment: You can generally count on the English professors who footnote Hamlet to get the grammar right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excellent construction that is, and certainly not grammatically deficient.

As [adjective] as

The comparison is well taken. This is not common, but it sounds almost poetic. I say almost because it can be nicely used in almost any situation. Nice turn of phrase.

Comment: +1 But it's not quite up to the original: "So excellent a king, that was to this / Hyperion to a satyr."

Comment: @StoneyB Maybe, but "as superior as" is more understandable I think.

Comment: @D_Bester: I disagree. Using "superior" in this way is clumsy and unnatural - probably mainly because we don't normally think in terms of some things being *more* or *less superior* than others. A simpler and more "understandable" way of putting it (which I'm sure is also *far* more common) would be to say *"...as **far above** my uncle as a god is above a beast."*

Comment: @FumbleFingers It may not be common but to my American ears it sounds good to say "as superior as". Not at all clumsy or unnatural. I don't know if it's an American versus British difference or whether it's simply an opinion difference, but I do think it's good to hear both opinions.

Comment: @D_Bester: I don't know if maybe there's some "irrelevant collocation" skewing things, but this NGram for [**is as superior to**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+as+superior+to&year_start=1830&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20as%20superior%20to%3B%2Cc0) suggests using "superior" in such "comparative" contexts has massively fallen out of favour. I can't see any particular US/UK split when I check with different corpuses.